# Search and replace in vimscript using a range?

Tags: vimscript, range

I was wondering how it is that I would place VIMScript variable values in my regex range and also in the replacement portion of my regex?

```
function! GoogleFormsStep(startnum, endnum)

    let x = startnum
    let line = 1

    while x <= endnum

      line, line s/$/x/g " What do I do here?

      let x = x + 1
      let line = line + 1
    endwhile

endfunction
```

Comment: A visual selection over the desired lines, followed by `:'<,'>s/$/\=line('.')/` (where `'<,'>` are automatically inserted) would seem to accomplish what's in your code (if it helps somewhere).

Comment: @VanLaser That worked great!  How about you put it as the answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:execute` and concatenation:

```
let startline = 2
let endline = 56
let searchpattern = "foo"
let replacepattern = "bar"

execute startline . "," . endline . "s/" . searchpattern ."/" . replacepattern . "/g"
```

Alternative:

```
let cmd = startline . "," . endline . "s/" . searchpattern ."/" . replacepattern . "/g"
execute cmd
```

Comment: Ah I didn't think this would involve concatenation, I guess execute is a bit like `eval` in Javascript for ':' commands.  Thank you.