# vim argument substitution inside a function

Tags: substitute, replace, functions

I would like to use the arguments passed to a function, as an argument to replace a search.

Something like this:

```
function! Myfunction(...)
    %s/hello/   goodBye a:1, a:2/g
endfunction
```

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Comment: You're looking for `:h :exe`. I won't be surprised for this question to be a duplicate of an another one.

Comment: I have looked into other questions without finding anything, if you can tell me something I can use, it would be appreciated. I am a beginner user, maybe I missed the answer from under my nose, given my inexperience

Comment: An extremely close Q/A is here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/search-and-replace-in-vimscript-using-a-range

Comment: thank you, I am trying, I am near to solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have any number of parameters, you'd have the choice between the following (untested) solutions

```
:exe '%s/hello/  goodbye '.join(a:000, ', ').'/'
```

(expecting the parameters contain no backslashes) or

```
:%s/hello/\='  goodbye '.join(a:000, ', ')/
```

This second solution works only when the dynamic part is used in the replacement text, not in the searched pattern.

See:

- [`:h :s\=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3as%5c%3d)
- [`:h join()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#join%28%29)
- [`:h :exe`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexe)

Comment: Note, that the argument should not contain a backslash